# How to determine if GPU supports Gamma Correction for OpenGL

Tags: opengl, gpu

So I'm reading up on [gamma correction](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/80986) which appears to be a GPU feature that really enhances the realism of lighting in a 3D game.

To take advantage of it with OpenGL, according to [this article](https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Gamma-Correction), you can set:

```
glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);
```

However, if I'm understanding all of this correctly, then if your GPU doesn't natively support gamma correction, then it doesn't matter whether you enable/activate it at the OpenGL layer, the setting will be ignored.

So I'm trying to figure out how to determine (programmatically) whether or not the system GPU support gamma correction. So that I can have OpenGL code that (essentially) looks like:

```
// Pseudo-code!
bool gammaCorrectionSupported = determineSomehow();
if(gammaCorrectionSupported == true) {
    glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB); 
}
```

**Does anybody have any ideas how I can `determineSomehow()`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gamma-correct rendering is a broad topic. You seem to be specifically referring to using sRGB images as output for a rendering operation, which the GPU hardware output will adjust properly to give a correct result in accord with the sRGB standard.

sRGB image rendering is a part of all OpenGL implementations for version 3.0 and above. So basically, if it was made in the last decade or so, it should work. For older OpenGL implementations, the extensions ARB_framebuffer_sRGB or EXT_framebuffer_sRGB can be tested. If either is present, then you can use those extensions to make it work.

However, sRGB conversion for fragment shader outputs requires two things: [enabling sRGB](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Colorspace) and rendering to an [image format that uses the sRGB colorspace](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#sRGB_colorspace). So whatever framebuffer you're rendering to needs to use an sRGB image format.

For an FBO, this is easy; you just pick an sRGB image format for the destination image. There are only two that are color-renderable, so it's an easy choice: `GL_SRGB8` or `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8`. For the default framebuffer, you will need to select a pixel format that uses the sRGB color space.